# Erlang message queue clutter

Tags: process, erlang, message-queue

I'm not quite sure how to go about finding the answer to this type of question. In Erlang each process has a message queue. There is the possibility that a message sent to a process may not match any pattern of that specific process. If that's the case the process leaves the message in the queue and goes on to check the other messages. My question is:

Doesn't this create a minor memory leak?

Hypothetically a process could continue to receive messages it can't match and grow and grow and grow eventually causing an issue. How does Erlang deal with this situation? I know Erlang has an implementation for timeouts, but if these messages didn't have a timeout would this cause a problem? Is there any sort of default garbage collection?

Comment: *Doesn't this create a minor memory leak?* -- Yes.  *How does Erlang deal with this situation?*  -- `Other -> ok`

Answer (score 4):

> Doesn't this create a minor memory leak?

Yes, a *selective receive* can cause a process to run out of memory.

> How does Erlang deal with this situation?

```
receive 
    Pattern1 -> %% do something;
    Pattern2 -> %% do something else;
    Other -> ok
end
```

Or, after some time passes:

```
myflush() ->
    receive 
        _Any -> myflush()
    after 0 ->  % If at any time there are no messages in the mailbox, this executes.
        ok
    end.
```

Comment: So the _Any -> myflush() simply calls the function again to continue to wait for potential messages. However, if the message does not match any pattern then the after occurs simply ending that process? Also thank you for the great response!

Comment: Actually, I found this on learnyousomeerlang "When that happens, the Erlang VM will try and find a message that fits one of the available patterns. In the case above, anything matches. As long as there are messages, the flush/0 function will recursively call itself until the mailbox is empty. Once this is done, the after 0 -> ok part of the code is executed and the function returns"